# How getting key of url of backend in frontend?

Tags: url-key

I need a blank page to receive a post of ajax and return json.

If I run the code below any page of backend, the link opens a blank page, that set up on my controller and router.

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('installments/adminhtml_ajax/'); ?>
```

But if I run into any page of the frontend, the key of the url is not the same and I am directed to the dashboard.

I do not know how to get the correct URL for the frontend, someone would have an idea that works?

Examples:

```
Backend  = installments/adminhtml_ajax/index/key/000085c50c4882df8a9cae52c8392227/
Frontend = installments/adminhtml_ajax/index/key/99edadac5bc5bb1e2421d3be38db525e/
```

Routers

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <installments>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Dexxtz_Installments</module>
                <frontName>installments</frontName>
            </args>
        </installments>         
    </routers>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <installments>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Dexxtz_Installments</module>
                <frontName>installments</frontName>
            </args>
        </installments>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Already changed the frontend for standard and nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you add your config.xml to your question?

Comment: Added routers @R.S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` in the url is generated based on the admin session.
And you cannot share the admin and frontend sessions, that's why when making the call from the frontend you get a different session key.

Anyway, it's not a good practice to make calls to backend actions from the frontend.
You should have 2 separate controllers, one for backend and one for frontend.
In order not to duplicate the code, you can put everything inside a method in a helper and just call that method in both controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Your front and admin `<routers>` (`<frontName>installments</frontName>`) should not be the same.

They are two ways to configure admin modules

1) Given it a different front name

```
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <installments>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Dexxtz_Installments</module>
                <frontName>admin_installments</frontName>
```

2) Put your module before/after adminhtml

```
<admin>
      <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Company_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">Company_Adminhtml</Company_Adminhtml>
```